How to unsafely get a concrete reference from a Box<dyn Trait>?
I want to reference the specific struct in a Box<dyn Trait>. I know exactly what the struct is so I am ok with using unsafe operations. When I typecast it using raw pointers it gives a SIGSEGV.
trait Help {}

struct Me {
    data: Vec<String>
}

impl Help for Me {}

fn main() {
    let me = Me { data: vec!["please".to_string(), "help".to_string()] };
    let me: Box<dyn Help> = Box::new(me);
    
    let inner = unsafe {
        *(me.as_ref() as *const dyn Help as *const &Me)
    };
    dbg!(&inner.data);
    assert_eq!(inner.data, vec!["hello", "world"]);
}

Playground link
I'm trying to avoid Any because the production logic doesn't have it and I want to peek into the internal state for tests.

Why are you trying to avoid Any? This is the proper way.

let inner = unsafe { &*(me.as_ref() as *const dyn Help as *const Me) }; but you should really not do this, since it depends on the exact layout of the fat pointer (&dyn Help) we are not supposed to be aware of.

@prog-fh The only problem is the extra & in &Me (but the as_ref() is also pretty unsafe and better replaced by &*).

If you don't want to use Any, just copy paste the code from the Any implementation, replacing Any with Help, it's just a couple lines (here)

@ChayimFriedman thanks for the solution it works! Please post it as an answer :D
I'm testing out a proof of concept, the actual implementation won't peek into the internal state so Any is not needed. I am peeking into the internal state only for testing. I'll add this context to the question.
btw Any uses something similar inside.

Well if it's only for test, that's a double reason not to use unsafe but rather use Any.

I think that peeking into the details in tests is not good, but even if you don't agree, it will still be better to add a trait AsAny { #[cfg(test)] fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any } and have it as a supertrait.

As I said in the comments, I believe it is a good idea to not do that with unsafe code, but if you really want, your mistake is the extra &:
let inner = unsafe { &*(&*me as *const dyn Help as *const Me) };

I also removed the as_ref() because it is risky, inference may turn it into things you didn't intend, and added a & in the beginning because it was required.

If you want to take ownership of the struct inside, you can first get a raw pointer using into_raw and then get the struct by dereferencing the new box constructed with the raw pointer. Thanks @kmdreko for pointing out the memory leak in my previous code.
fn main() {
    let me = Me { data: vec!["please".to_string(), "help".to_string()] };
    let me: Box<dyn Help> = Box::new(me);
    let p = Box::into_raw(me) as *mut Me;
    let inner = unsafe {
        *Box::from_raw(p)
    };
    dbg!(&inner.data);
    assert_eq!(inner.data, vec!["hello", "world"]);
}


I don't think it leaks. There's nothing allocated for a box. It's just a pointer to something else. If you look at the source code of for Drop for Box, it does nothing except for deallocating the pointer inside.
Yep, I agree with the second comment.

What's Miri? Maybe I am wrong and I should take a look. But I think the pointer is the vector and it gets deallocated when inner goes out of scope.

Sorry I am wrong. I will edit my answer to reflect that.
